# String.valueOf() giving random values

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to create a string from a byte array but it gives me some random value. The byte array is encrypted, so I'm not sure I'm decrypting correctly. The random values look like -[B@1uy3798. Each time it gives different random value. How can I solve this?

```
public class MainActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Key publicKey = null;
    Key privateKey = null;
    byte[] encoded;
    byte[] text = new byte[0];

    try {
      text = "This is my secret message".getBytes();

      Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
      encoded = c.doFinal(text);

      c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
      text = c.doFinal(encoded);

      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception encountered. Exception is " +    e.getMessage());
      }
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(text)); //get random values here
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling the `toString()` on the byte array.

Comment: You should report any exceptions you catch, not just silently ignore them. Perhaps you are missing a simple error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.valueOf(text)` doesn't do what you think it does. What you want is `new String(text)`.

`String.valueOf(text)` returns a string representation of the pointer to the array (its hashcode). You want to turn the array into a String, so use the appropriate constructor.

To explain why you're getting this value returned, you should look at the contract of toString() in java.lang.Object:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method. The toString method for class Object
>   returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the
>   object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned
>   hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other
>   words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

To put it all together, you get -[B@1uy3798 because The [B is the name of the class byte[] (you'll see this in bytecode if you disassemble the class file), followed by '@', followed by 1uy3798. If you were to run the class again and call hashCode() on the byte[] text, you'd see that the hashcode matches the value you're seeing in the Toast.

Comment: So,how can I solve this error buddy,can yu give me an example code,using new String(text) will solve the problem??

Comment: Re-read my answer. It contains the solution. Use `new String(text)`. If it solves the problem, please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Now am getting this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:119)
                                                                  at chatra.alert.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:122)

Comment: I have updated my code pls refer that..

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess. You assign the variable several times. I have made an edit that should clear it up, but it's awaiting peer review. Once my code-change edit is approved, you should be able to see how to fix it.